# How to call a function from another function?

Tags: javascript

I have a complex code.this is its sample.i can not change structure. how can i call `e()` in `f()`?

```
a=function b()
    {
        var c,d;
        c=function()
        {
              function e()
              {
              ...
              }
              ...
        }
        d=function()
        {
              function f()
              {
              //i need e() here
              }
              ....
        }

}
```

Comment: You can't. `e` is local to `c`, so why would you need it?

Comment: How are `a`, `d` and `f` called? How is `c` called?

Comment: thank u and it's complicated code and i want to change it and i cant explain it easily.

Comment: It can't be that complicated, try it. Do you use closures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. That's the whole point of scoping.

You can, however, make the variable `e` available to the parent scope by declaring it outside the function `c`.

```
a = function b() {
  var c, d, e;
  c = function () {
    e = function () {
      ...
    };
    ...
  };
  d = function () {
    function f() {
      e();
    }
    ...
  };
};
```

Comment: That would need `c` to have been called before `d`/`f`, which could be confusing.

Comment: what if i have one e() in d() and another in c(). i have to change its name?

Comment: No, just call it how you normally would: `e()` in both `d` and `c`

Comment: just same name with different functionality

Answer (score 2):

You can't as those are local functions within different scopes and are not accessible from each other. If you need to call `e()` from inside `f()`'s scope, then `e()` shouldn't be defined within `c()`'s scope, but within `b()`, where it will be visible in `f()`'s scope.